# (Excel) Return true if all items in list are identical (with varying list sizes)

Tags: excel, indexing, dynamic, match

I'm trying to find a formula that will return TRUE/FALSE based on whether the values in a certain range are all identical or not.

That part is pretty simple, but I'd also like to have a dynamic lookup range, i.e. I have hundreds of different ranges that each need this formula, and they are of different sizes. They are all just a single column, but they vary in length (# of rows). So, I'm thinking of something that will, for example, recognize that there is an empty cell after the last item in the list and stop searching there.

Here's an example of the kinds of lists I'm working with:

72256
72256
72256
72256
72256

75432
75444

So, I'd like a formula that would look at the first list and return "True" (because all the values are identical, but that would return "False" for the second list (because not all the values are identical). And I don't want to have to specify the ranges manually, because there are hundreds of different lists (of different lengths). The lists are all in a single column, and they are all made up of values in adjacent rows (with an empty cell between each list).

I have the following formula, and it works just fine, BUT it doesn't incorporate a dynamic-range element:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(A1:A9,A1:A9,0),ROW(A1:A9)-ROW(A1)+1)>0))=1

Answer (score 2):

Will you be able to enter the formulas manually or do you need VBA? If you can do it manually you could do something like:

=IF(Count(YourRange)=CountIf(YourRange;FirstOfYourRange);True;False)

Basically you just compare the number of items in the range to the number which are equal to the first. If both are the same, all elements in the range are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Select B1 and create a Named Formula:

```
myRng   Refers to:  =OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,0,0,MATCH(TRUE,(Sheet1!A1:A100 = ""),0)-1)
```

Note that Addressing is in Relative mode.  The range will adjust to a range that starts with the first cell to the left (in this case A1), and extends down until (but not including) the first blank cell.

By entering the formula below in the cell that is adjacent to the upper left corner of the range, it will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`

```
=FREQUENCY(myRng,myRng)=COUNTA(myRng)
```

The location of the dynamic range is determined in part by the selected cell where you create the formula, and the addressing mode used within the named formula.

So if you want the results elsewhere, it is usually just a matter of defining `myRng` appropriately.

[image]